# Confusion about the integral $\int^1_0dx\int^{(1-x)}_xf(t)dt$, where $f$ is continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

It's from a question asking to find the value of $\int^1_0dx\int^{(1-x)}_xf(t)dt$, where $f$ is continuous.
I know how to solve the question, but I just confuse about the integral itself. Is it evaluated the integral on a plane or on a line? Since it is a iterated integral, it seems to be evaluated on a plane, but the whole integral is only about one variable $x$, then it is like to be evaluated on a line. So which is right? Thanks.

Comment: The integral is taken over the region defined by $0\le x\le1$ and $t$ either increasing or decreasing from $x$ to $1-x$. It looks like two isosceles triangles appended to one another in the $(x,t)$ plane.

Comment: @PeterForeman Then it feels like $f$ is firstly a function of $t$, then a function of a different variable $x$. I know one can use different notation to express the same function. But here $t$ and $x$ seems to have some essential differences, for example, their ranges seem to be different. So does $f$ still well defined in this situation?

Comment: This integral makes complete sense. Physically this would be the weighted area of the above region where the density function $g(x,t)=f(t)$ only varies with respect to the $t$ axis (i.e. density is constant along the $x$ axis).

Answer (score 0):

For integral you have 2 variables $(x, t)$ so you have limits
$$ \left( \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{x}^{1-x}+ \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{1-x}^{x} \right) f(t)dxdt$$
As to your integrand function, then it depend on one variable.

Comment: @Peter Foreman. I understand what you mean, but let's follow steps: how to understand first integral? If from it conclude min/max principle for $t$, then we obtain well defined figure(left right triangles) and this last do not need "-". One more - suppose you want to write integral on obtained figure, then how would you do it in one symbol? min/max in limits?